# When hover on a child apply effects to the parent

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I want to apply the transform to the `.card-page-container` only when hover on `.card-img`. I try this but it doesn't work.

It's a card with image and on the bottom a popover and I only want to apply the transition when the image is hovere

##### JSX

```
<article className='card-page-container'>
     <div className='card-img'
          onClick={() => {
               props.setPageSelected(props.page);
               props.setCardSelected(true);
          }}>
          <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/287/250/300'
               alt={props.page.name}
          />
     </div>
</article>
```

##### SCSS

```
.card-page-container{
    // size
    height: 375px;

    // margin
    padding: 2rem;

    // decoration
    border-radius: 24px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);

    // transition
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform .1s ease-in;

    .card-img{
        // size
        height: 80%;

        // decoration
        cursor: pointer;

        img{
            @include img();
            
            // decoration
            border-radius: 16px;
        }
        
        :hover{
            & + .card-page-container{
                transform: scale(1.1);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd do much better showing us rendered HTML and compiled CSS in a demo snippet using the editor. We all have to use our imaginations when working with this code. See [ask] and take the [tour] for more tips.